# how to highlight a button on press of other button

Tags: jquery, button, user-interface

I have two buttons i need to highlight one button when other has pressed.  how can i get it?

Comment: In what environment are the buttons? (What language are you using...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming javascript/jquery....

```
$("#button-1").click(function(){
    $("button-2").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Comment: no problem :) If it helped, mind bestowing on me the green check of goodness? Thanks much :) Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: can you tell me how to zoom in and out specific part of an Image view when it satisfies a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just assume you have two buttons bt1, bt.
Set the default color of those buttons to some color.
bt1.setBackgroundcolor(colorname);
bt21.setBackgroundcolor(colorname);
now  in onClickListener of bt1 set the Background color of the bt2 to some other color except the default color.
it's like 
bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClick...)
{
public void onClick(view v)
{
bt2.setBackgroundColor(newcolorname);
}

}
now you reset the buttons background color where you want and that's it.